# cURL to call API in PHP not working

Tags: php, curl

I have tried calling the API using standard URL. All work perfectly directly from the browser. For e.g.:

http://www.worldcat.org/webservices/catalog/search/sru?query=srw.su%3D%22Computer organization%22&startRecord=101&maximumRecords=100&wskey=7Rn7E7osoeJeQURAiEO4GH74HZa6BLdt7eXahgxdvwnfO6Ph7za1OzU9M2zx0e9nuDHVO34b5HfnLuOw

http://www.worldcat.org/webservices/catalog/search/sru?query=srw.su%3D%22Computer engineering%22&startRecord=101&maximumRecords=100&wskey=7Rn7E7osoeJeQURAiEO4GH74HZa6BLdt7eXahgxdvwnfO6Ph7za1OzU9M2zx0e9nuDHVO34b5HfnLuOw

But when I use cURL to do it, I keep on having the error from the API that the wskey is not attached:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
d($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

d($OCLCqueries);
foreach ($OCLCqueries as $OCLCquery) {
    // echo "managed1";
    $XMLdata = curl_get_contents($OCLCquery);
    // echo "managed2";
}
```

I defined $OCLCqueries earlier. It is an array that contains the URL calls as values.
d() is a function that I call from an installed library which is a more sophisticated form of var_dump(), basically having the same purpose (serve as breakpoints for debugging) but dumping the data in a more human-readable format.

This is the output I have:

```
<body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - org.oclc.wskey.api.WSKeyException: WsKeyParam(wskey) not found in request</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>org.oclc.wskey.api.WSKeyException: WsKeyParam(wskey) not found in request</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (org.oclc.wskey.api.WSKeyException: WsKeyParam(wskey) not found in request).</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3></h3></body>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: actually the problem is that there is a space in `Computer organization` in the URL. replace the space with %20, so it says `Computer%20organization` instead, and it works fine: `http://www.worldcat.org/webservices/catalog/search/sru?query=srw.su%3D%22Computer%20organization%22&startRecord=101&maximumRecords=100&wskey=7Rn7E7osoeJeQURAiEO4GH74HZa6BLdt7eXahgxdvwnfO6Ph7za1OzU9M2zx0e9nuDHVO34b5HfnLuOw` - Google Chrome recognize that error when pasting it in, and fixes it automatically - but Curl doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I thought the most likely reason for the failure was a lack of `User-Agent` string in the request but found, when testing the code below, that it's existence or not made no difference so I believe the problem is the format of the url used in the cURL request as it is already encoded. By separating the baseurl and the parameters as below it works fine.

```
$url='http://www.worldcat.org/webservices/catalog/search/sru';
$params=array(
    'query'             =>  'srw.su="Computer organization"',
    'startRecord'       =>  101,
    'maximumRecords'    =>  100,
    'wskey'             =>  '7Rn7E7osoeJeQURAiEO4GH74HZa6BLdt7eXahgxdvwnfO6Ph7za1OzU9M2zx0e9nuDHVO34b5HfnLuOw'
);


function curl_get_contents( $url=false, $params=array() ){
    if( $url && !empty( $params ) ){

        $url = $url . '?' . http_build_query( $params );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0' );

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return (object)array(
            'response'  =>  $data,
            'info'      =>  $info
        );
    }
}

$data = curl_get_contents( $url, $params );
print_r( $data->response );
```

To simplify the call to the main function you could create a simple wrapper function like this.

```
function getcatalog( $baseurl=false, $term=false, $start=1, $max=1, $key=false ){
    if( $baseurl && $term && $key ){
        $params=array(
            'query'             =>  'srw.su="'.$term.'"',
            'startRecord'       =>  $start,
            'maximumRecords'    =>  $max,
            'wskey'             =>  $key
        );
        return curl_get_contents( $baseurl, $params );
    }
}

$data = getcatalog( $url, 'Computer organization', 1, 100,'7Rn7E7osoeJeQURAiEO4GH74HZa6BLdt7eXahgxdvwnfO6Ph7za1OzU9M2zx0e9nuDHVO34b5HfnLuOw');
if( $data->info['http_code']==200 ){
    print_r( $data->response );
}
```

Comment: actually the problem in OP's post is that there is a space in `Computer organization` in the URL. replace the space with %20, so it says `Computer%20organization` instead, and it works fine: `http://www.worldcat.org/webservices/catalog/search/sru?query=srw.su%3D%22Computer%20organization%22&startRecord=101&maximumRecords=100&wskey=7Rn7E7osoeJeQURAiEO4GH74HZa6BLdt7eXahgxdvwnfO6Ph7za1OzU9M2zx0e9nuDHVO34b5HfnLuOw` - Google Chrome recognize that error when pasting it in, and fixes it automatically - but Curl doesn't.